# Laravel Excel Installation

Tags: php, inversion-of-control, laravel-5, phpexcel

I've just used composer to get Maatwebsite Laravel-Excel. I am about to use it but I am brand new to installing/using packages. So far I've only used what is shipped with Laravel.
I'm reading [the documentation](http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs/getting-started) and am following the steps (I've done the first three steps) but I am confused by this line;

```
The class is binded to the ioC as excel

$excel = App::make('excel');
```

I don't really know what most of that means. I have read up a little on ioC and then Dependency Injection (also new to me). But I still don't know - is this part of the docs telling me to do something?? I ran `php artisan` on the command line (for another purpose) and I got this back;

```
[2015-04-23 13:42:09] local.ERROR: exception 'BadMethodCallException' with message 'Call to undefined method [package]' in /vagrant/source/laravel-excel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/ServiceProvider.php:226
Stack trace:
#0 /vagrant/source/laravel-excel/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/ExcelServiceProvider.php(45): Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider->__call('package', Array)
#1 /vagrant/source/laravel-excel/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/ExcelServiceProvider.php(45): Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider->package('maatwebsite/exc...')
#2 [internal function]: Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider->boot()
#3 /vagrant/source/laravel-excel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(523): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#4 /vagrant/source/laravel-excel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(703): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#5 /vagrant/source/laravel-excel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(685): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootProvider(Object(Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider))
#6 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider), 19)
#7 /vagrant/source/laravel-excel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(686): array_walk(Array, Object(Closure))
#8 /vagrant/source/laravel-excel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/BootProviders.php(15): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->boot()
#9 /vagrant/source/laravel-excel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(181): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#10 /vagrant/source/laravel-excel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(195): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#11 /vagrant/source/laravel-excel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(92): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#12 /vagrant/source/laravel-excel/artisan(36): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#13 {main}
```

`php artisan` ran sucessfully when I took out the maatwebsite references in config/app.php - so there must be more to do here but I don't know what.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the documentation is listing the wrong version. The 1.x branch is meant for Laravel 4.x. The [GitHub page](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel)  provides a better guide for Laravel 5 users. Try changing the version to 2.* in your composer.json and re-run composer update. Add the correct references back to your app.php you should be able to run php artisan without errors.

The App::make('excel') command should also work after that.

Comment: Thanks. Where do I put App::make('excel')? In my controller?

Comment: Wherever you need an instance of the Excel class. App::make('excel') is basically the same as new \Maatwebsite\Laravel-Excel\Excel() or since you've added an alias in your app config: new excel()

Comment: @Maarten00 i install Excel using composer im also stuck now i don't know how to move forward create model or controller where i have to start...?

Comment: @HamelRaj Well it all depends on what you are trying to do and how you have defined your domain. I personally use Laravel Eloquent models exclusively for database communication. So I would create a seperate model for business logic and use the Excel class there. But it all comes down to your own preference. You can use \App::make() anywhere beyond the index.php of Laravel to create an instance of a class. You don't even have to, you could also just use a vanilla-php style statement: 'new \Maatwebsite\Laravel-Excel\Excel()'

Comment: @Maarten00 i installed and im still confuse here `$excel = App::make('excel');` but i typed php artisan tinker and then enterd `$excel = App::make('excel');` so i don't know what happing that step i hope my installation correct

Comment: @Maarten00 i have table call jobs table with some columns i want generate document particular two date so i don't know what is next step to do after installation

Comment: @Maarten00 i already have JobsController with CRUD process so to generate what i want do pplz help me ??

Comment: @HamelRaj Your starting point should be the Maatwebsite docs: http://www.maatwebsite.nl/laravel-excel/docs

Personally I no longer use this plugin, but the vanilla PHPExcel library because it has a lot of features that are not covered in this port.